# How to get the values and parse them from an foreach loop

Tags: php

I am trying to loop an array and use it's value for my html code...

I have

```
array as...

title1
http://link...
1024 //window width
700  //window height

title2
http://link2...
1024 //window width
700  //window height

more...
```

My foreach loop.

```
 foreach ($line as $field){

       echo "<a href='http://link...'>title1</a>";
       echo "<h1>1024</h1>"; //window width
       echo "<h2>700</h2>";  //window height
   }
```

How can do distingquish these values and show them in the page? Thanks for the help!

Comment: Are you reading this data from a file (I got this impression because of the variable `$line`) ? Or is your data already in a php array?

Comment: yes I am reading data from a csv file.

Comment: and how are the 4 fields (title, url, width, height) separated? are they in 4 different lines? or are they comma-separated in the same line?

Comment: only comma separated in the same line...

Comment: So: (title,link,width,height) for each line?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on your comments, your data has a comma-separated format with all 4 fields in one line:

```
title1,http://url1...,1024,720
title2,http://url2...,1024,720
```

Simply, read the file line-by-line, then use `explode` to split the line into an array (using the comma `,` as delimeter).

```
foreach ($line in $all_file_lines){   // for each line in the file
   $fields = explode(',', $line);     // split the line into the 4 fields
   echo "<a href='$fields[1]'>$fields[0]</a>";
   echo "<h1>$fields[2]</h1>"; //window width
   echo "<h2>$fields[3]</h2>";  //window height
```

}

Answer (score 0):

If your data is already in a PHP array and named `$line`:

```
foreach ($line as $field){

   echo "<a href='".$field['link']."'>".$field['title']."</a>";
   echo "<h1>".$field['width']."</h1>";
   echo "<h1>".$field['height']."</h1>";
}
```

BUT, your array has to have the key naming set appropriately (link, title, width, height).

Hope this helps.